# how to show error message for textfield validation based on server response

Tags: ajax, extjs, extjs3

I have a `textfield` which has to be validated based on the user input.By validate what I mean is, I need to check if the name exists in the database and if it exists display error message accordingly.

How I am doing this is, I have a `change listener` for the `text box`, within the listener I have a `ajax request` which connects to a `java action` and check if name already exists in db, and sends back a `response`. On `ajax success`, I am trying to `set error message`... But the error message is not being set..

```
{
                        fieldLabel : 'Company Name:',
                        xtype : 'textfield',
                        required: true,
                        allowBlank : false,
                        name : 'companyName',
                         msgTarget: 'side',
                        listeners : {
                            change : function(th,n,o) {
                            console.log("change-EV");
/*****ajax request here****/
                            this.markInvalid('N.V..!');
                //          this.setActiveError('NV..',false);
                            },
                            blur: function(th){
                                console.log("Blur-ev");
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Is the approach I am using right? Will I be able to achieve this with ajax request?

Comment: Pelase go through Remote Filtering in this article. http://skirtlesden.com/articles/extjs-comboboxes-part-2.
This can help.

Comment: Kindly see the comment on subhadip's post, I dont want to use store filter for that purpose I guess?correct me if I am wrong

Comment: How many distinct values are already in the DB? If hundreds, would it be possible to download them to the client beforehand?

Comment: @PeterIvan  Yea not more than hundreds currently, probably that is something I would like to try... if u are aware of how that can be done, it will be helpful if u could share some ref links?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using change event of textfield it will get fired for every letter typed

If you use blur then it will get fired when you move to other element 
as per my understanding of your problem in your case you should use blur event

as blur fired make a ajax call for check and if country name exists throw the exception from server side, it will fail the ajax call

so you can show the error message in ajax failure callback

Comment: change( this, newValue, oldValue )
Fires just before the field blurs if the field value has changed.

Comment: I think change is fired for every letter typed I created a fiddle Try out there  (https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/l28)

Comment: I agree with u, Ext JS 5 documentation says, change( this, newValue, oldValue, eOpts )
Fires when the value of a field is changed via the setValue method., But I am using Ext JS 3.4 where the change event is fired just before blur event.

Comment: ohh so you are using Ext JS 3.4, then try this one  [link]     https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/l4g did the same thing in change event

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you are trying to make Ajax call for every letter typed,
Is that right ? because this might be a lot of overhead on the server. Can we use a combobox with list of names in the the store bound to the combobox, then filter based on the type ahead just filter the values from the store using store.filterBy().

Comment: No, not for every letter typed..once u type in the textfield and move to any other form element.. the change event will be fired.

Comment: And my purpose is to avoid duplication when adding new items. Like, if I am creating a new company say, name of the company is 'new Company'. Then before adding it to the database I want to check if their exists a company by that name, and if it exists display an error telling 'duplicate entry'.

Comment: On form submit you can validate it on the server side whether the record exists in the db and respond accordingly and just show the response.

Comment: Yeah that is one way of achieving it..but is it not possible to do it through an ajax request and display error before form submit?

Comment: Since you want to call the backend service on Blur or once your focus shifts to some other portion of the form, the use of change event is not relevant here. When ever you enter anything on the textField it is a change, and the change event will be called. You can use blur event to make the ajax call and mark it valid/invalid in the request callback.

Comment: @Subhadip  right now, I am displaying the response in alert message...I wanted to know how to mark a field as invalid and display a message in the form itself., because I tried that and it did not work

Comment: @extUser if you want to just mark the form element invalid, in your method callback use -->   combo.markInvalid();  http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-method-markInvalid